# Unable to filter columns while importing CSV

Tags: r

I was trying to import a big CSV by filtering few columns . So basically I just wanted couple of fields only. I ran the code

```
data <- read.csv.sql("D:/ABC June16.csv",
                  sql = "select Zone,Region from file",
                  sep = "\t")
```

Got the error

> Error in sqliteSendQuery(con, statement, bind.data) : 
>     error in statement: no such column: Zone

But I have both the column Zone and Region in my CSV. Any idea why is this happening ?

Comment: Questions on SO should provide a complete minimal self contained reproducible example that anyone else can copy and paste into their session to reproduce the error.

Comment: Your file is tab separated?

Comment: Roland I just got the data in excel and saved it as  CSV, there's a chance since its CSV it might be comma separated as well ..I tried data <- read.csv.sql("D:/ABC June16.csv",
                  sql = "select Zone,Region from file",
                  sep = ",") this as well but not working ...

Comment: If it was exported from Excel it is either comma separated or the sperator is a `;` (depending on you locale). You know that you can open a CSV in a text editor and check, right?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to use **fread** from the excellent data.table package:

```
library(data.table)
fread("D:/ABC June16.csv", select = c("Zone", "Region"))
```

Comment: Thanks..I tried fread but it is saying I need a 64 bit machine as the memory is falling short..so had to try this other option..thanks for the suggestion anyways...

Comment: @s-b How big is the csv file? I am pretty sure you have a 64bit machine, are you sure it was not related to it detecting large integers, that it wants to store in a 64bit integer, using bit64?